# movement meaning in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

The word "movement" has many definitions in the dictionary. Which of them is proper in the following sentence?

> So you've probably studied both of these **movement**s separately,
>   separate movements, Realism and Impressionism, in some of your art
>   history courses.

I found in the Merriam-webster dictionary definitions like "tendency" or "trend", but I am not sure about the meaning in this context.

Comment: Hi M. Afrashteh. Have you found any definition of "movement" that you think *might* be correct? What is your best guess?

Comment: Hi @Tashus. I found in the Merriam-webster dictionary (not others) definitions like tendency or trend. But anyway, I am not sure about them.

Comment: To the VTC'er, the definition in Merriam-Webster indeed only refers to political or social movements, and it may not be clear to nonnative speakers that a similar meaning applies to art.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Movement" in your example refers to an [art movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_movement), "a tendency or style in art with a specific common philosophy or goal, followed by a group of artists during a restricted period of time".